# can't be loaded because another AssetBundle with the same files is already loaded. error while loading different bundles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've tried load asset bundles from URLs. When I load only single asset bundle, it works well. But if I try to load multiple asset bundles, Unity gives this error: `The AssetBundle 'https://example.com/uc?export=download&id=1234567' can't be loaded because another AssetBundle with the same files is already loaded.`

example code as follows

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using TMPro;

public class sahnecagir : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI Log;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(LoadBundleFromUrl("https://example.com/uc?export=download&id=123456", 2, 0, (uint)Crc.Gifts));
    }

    IEnumerator LoadBundleFromUrl(string url, int tip, uint version, uint crc)
    {
        using (UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequestAssetBundle.GetAssetBundle(url, version, crc))
        {
            uwr.SendWebRequest();

            while (!uwr.isDone)
            {
                if(tip == 1) Log.text = "Rooms loading " + (uwr.downloadProgress * 100).ToString("0")  + "%";
                else if(tip == 2) Log.text = "Gifts loading " + (uwr.downloadProgress * 100).ToString("0")  + "%";
               
                yield return null;
            }

            if (uwr.isNetworkError || uwr.isHttpError)
            {
                Debug.Log(uwr.error);
            }
            else
            {
                if (tip == 1)
                {
                    MainConfig.Instance.RoomBgBundle = DownloadHandlerAssetBundle.GetContent(uwr);
                }
                else if (tip == 2)
                {
                    MainConfig.Instance.GiftBundle = DownloadHandlerAssetBundle.GetContent(uwr);
                }
            }

           

            if (uwr.isDone && tip == 1)
            {
                Log.text = "Rooms loading 100%";
                StartCoroutine(LoadBundleFromUrl("https://example.com/uc?export=download&id=1234567", 2, 0, 0));
            }
            else
            {
                Log.text = "Gifts loading 100%";
            }
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you create your bundles? Sounds like your AssetBundles share some common files => As Unity is telling you it can't load the same file multiple times. Either consider unloading a bundle once it is isn't needed anymore or include these common files into your build or download them in a different way only once

Comment: @derHugo Hi, there is no same file in different bundles. For instance, bundle one contains: assets/resources/rooms/1.png - 2png so on, bundle two contains, assets/resources/gifts/gift1.png - gift2.png etc

Comment: Hi there, how do you end up solving this problem?

Comment: @SeakyLone Does my answer resolve your issue?

Comment: @yasirkula No, in my case, my asset bundles have distinctive names just like Demir's case. My current workaround is unload the asset bundle right after it is loaded in scenes, which looks pretty weird and needs more patching code for but works for now.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I've been trying to modify a bundle with different files but Unity refuses to load the two different files even if they have different names, a different structure, different files inside, nothing.

Opening the bundle in Notepad++ brings up what I assume to be a "container name" of CAB-a317cdbf067bab183d6dd12d870c1407 as an example. This is what Unity seems to be checking for to determine whether a bundle is "identical."

A simple find and replace to a different name and boom. The bundles load now.

Answer (score 0):

If multiple AssetBundles were created with the same [AssetBundleBuild.assetBundleName](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundleBuild-assetBundleName.html) parameter, this issue can occur. Giving unique `assetBundleName`s per AssetBundle can resolve this issue (even if you rename the generated AssetBundle file afterwards).